# Excel drag handle auto-fill giving erroneous values (from cache/memory)

Tags: excel, autofill

I use the auto-fill handle very often; both dragging and double-clicking.  I need it, so I don't want to disable it in the options.  However, I have certain situations where I'm just trying to copy down values to the next cells, and it appears Excel is using some type of memory/cache to auto-fill them with crazy values.  I recognize the values; but there is no rhyme or reason as to why it's auto-filling them at this moment in time.

Example:  There are no formulas in any of these cells and this is just a brand new sheet in Excel.  I want to grab handle of cell B10 and copy it down to B14:

[image]

Now, I wish I could record a little clip of me copying this down so you can see it change the values live, but I promise you, this is what the values get changed to, and it has no relation to the values above it in the same column or anywhere in this sheet and there are zero formulas anywhere; just a simple table being populated:

[image]

What can I do to get this to copy the correct values?  This has created errors in other tables where I didn't catch it populating the cells incorrectly in time.

Comment: You probably need to turn off the **Flash Fill** option, check this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-Flash-Fill-on-3f9bcf1e-db93-4890-94a0-1578341f73f7

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that before posting.  Still auto-filling incorrectly with that unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague has been suffering this exact problem and his solution is detailed below:
Go into Advanced Options and under General click on Edit Custom Lists button and you should find your values listed there. If so, you can delete them from this list and the problem should go away
Good luck!

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, that must be it.  However, those lists are needed for custom sorting elsewhere.  I had no idea there would be any relation between that and an auto-fill.  I'll see if I can work around it.  Any way to kill the strange linkage between custom lists for sorting, and an auto-fill?